# JPA delete row in many-many table with additional column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a many to many relationship between Project and ClientEmployee. I tried to use a composite primary key in the JoinTable ProjectClientEmployee but that did not work.

So I created the relationship using just an auto generated id. Here are the class definitions.

**Join Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project_clientemployee")
public class ProjectClientEmployee extends GenericModel{

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="projectId", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Project project;

    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="clientEmployeeId", referencedColumnName="id")
    public ClientEmployee clientEmployee;

    public String role; // additional column

    ...
}
```

**Project Class**

```
@Entity
public class Project extends GenericModel {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="project", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<ProjectClientEmployee> clientEmployees = new ArrayList();

    ...
}
```

**Employee Class**

```
@Entity
public class ClientEmployee extends Person {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="clientEmployee", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<ProjectClientEmployee> projects = new ArrayList();

    ...
}
```

Now, I am successfully able to create associations (rows are created in the join table), But I am unable to delete these relations.

**Adding employees to project** This works..

```
public void addClientEmployee(ClientEmployee clientEmployee, String role){
    ProjectClientEmployee clientEmployeeAssoc = new ProjectClientEmployee();
    clientEmployeeAssoc.project = this;
    clientEmployeeAssoc.clientEmployee = clientEmployee;
    clientEmployeeAssoc.role = role;    
    this.clientEmployees.add(clientEmployeeAssoc);
    clientEmployee.projects.add(clientEmployeeAssoc);
}
```

But removing does not work. To remove I just create a new list and populate with new Employees, and then set the project list to be that list.

```
project.clientEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
for(ClientEmployee clientEmployee : newClientEmployees){
   project.addClientEmployee(clientEmployee, "Project Lead");
}
```

But this does not empty the list first. It just adds on top of the old list. (i.e it does not delete the previous records.)

**Question**: Why isn't  `project.clientEmployees = new ArrayList<>();` and then `project.save()` auto deleting records from the association table.

Comment: To remove an entity from the database, you must explicitely remove it, using `em.remove()`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @JBNizet - Tnx. But shouldn't JPA automatically remove or add to the association table based on the new list? I would think by just `project.clientEmployees = new ArrayList<>();` and saving project, all the associations should be deleted. I do that for my other @OneToMany relations and it works...I was thinking it might be that the association table has two foreign keys so does not auto do it?

Comment: It works on a OneToMany if orphanRemoval is true. In this case, you should delete the entity.

Comment: Okay, using `JPA.em.remove(<entity>)` works. I was using Play! Framework specific `<entity>.delete()` and it was not working.